# Weighted Probability Problem in Swift

Tags: interview-questions, swift, mapreduce

I was asked a weighted probability question in a technical interview a few months ago that went something like this:

> Given an input of colors and an integer "weight" value, randomly return a color based on its weight.

The sample input would be something like this:

```
[("Red", 20), ("Blue", 50), ("Green", 70)]
```

The probability that each color would be returned would be something like:

Red: 20/140

Blue: 50/140

Green: 70/140

(where 140 is the sum of the weight of the input colors)

I was thinking about this recently and decided to give it another go in Swift.

My first pass was:

```
func weightedColor(input: [(String, Int)]) -> String {

    var total = 0

    for tuple in input {
        total += tuple.1
    }

    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total)))

    var sum = 0
    for tuple in input {
        let range = sum + tuple.1

        if rand <= range {
            return tuple.0
        } else {
            sum += tuple.1
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

Then I realized I could optimize the total weight calculation with map-reduce:

```
let total = UInt32(input.map { $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine: +))
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
func weightedColor(input: [(String, Int)]) -> String {

    let total = UInt32(input.map { $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine: +))

    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(total))

    var sum = 0
    for tuple in input {
        let range = sum + tuple.1

        if rand <= range {
            return tuple.0
        } else {
            sum += tuple.1
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

I don't like the `for tuple in input` loop and feel it can be optimized further.  How can I improve this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one error in your implementation: The test
`if rand <= range` must be `if rand < range`, otherwise the returned 
values are not correctly distributed according to the given weights.
You can check that with the input list

```
[("Red", 1), ("Blue", 1)]
```

which returns only "Red" without this fix.

Apart from that, your code looks correct, but there are some
possible improvements.

- The final `return ""` is never reached unless you made a programming
  error. Instead of returning *some* value (in order to satisfy the compiler), replace it by

  ```
  fatalError("This should never be reached")
  ```

  This will stop the program execution immediately, and
  `fatalError()` has the `@noreturn` attribute, so the compiler won't
  complain about a missing return value.
- Replace `for tuple in input { }` by `for (color, weight) in input`,
  that allows you to get rid of the non-descriptive `tuple.0` and `tuple.1`
  in the loop body.
- Add the current weight to the sum *before* testing against `rand`,
  that makes the `range` variable obsolete.

The function does then look like this:

```
func weightedColor(input: [(String, Int)]) -> String {

    let total = UInt32(input.map { $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine: +))
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(total))

    var sum = 0
    for (color, weight) in input {
        sum += weight
        if rand < sum {
            return color
        }
    }

    fatalError("This should never be reached")
}
```

The next step is to make the function *generic*. 
There is nothing which is special to colors or strings,
so you can simply replace `String` by a generic type `T`:

```
func weightedRandomElement<T>(items: [(T, Int)]) -> T {

    let total = UInt32(items.map { $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine: +))
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(total))

    var sum = 0
    for (element, weight) in items {
        sum += weight
        if rand < sum {
            return element
        }
    }

    fatalError("This should never be reached")
}
```

Then the same function can be used to get a random color:

```
let colors = [("Red", 20), ("Blue", 50), ("Green", 70)]
let color = weightedRandomElement(colors)
```

or a random number:

```
let numbers = [(3.1415, 20), (2.71827, 50)]
let number = weightedRandomElement(numbers)
```

or anything else.

---

*Update:* As @hashemi correctly said, the `fatalError()` point would 
also be reached if the function is called with an empty array.
Actually that would also happen if the function is called with a non-empty array but the sum of the given weights is zero. These
situations could be considered as a programming error on the caller's side and can be checked with a  `precondition()`.

@hashemi also suggested to use `UInt` instead of `Int` as data type
for the weights. This is more natural because the weights must not
be negative (and unexpected results would happen for negative input).

Then the function looks like this:

```
func weightedRandomElement<T>(items: [(T, UInt)]) -> T {

    let total = items.map { $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine: +)
    precondition(total > 0, "The sum of the weights must be positive")

    let rand = UInt(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total)))

    var sum = UInt(0)
    for (element, weight) in items {
        sum += weight
        if rand < sum {
            return element
        }
    }

    fatalError("This should never be reached")
}
```

and is called like

```
let colors : [(String, UInt)] = [("Red", 20), ("Blue", 50), ("Green", 70)]
let color = weightedRandomElement(colors)
```

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) The `fatalError` will be reached if an empty array is passed. You can either `guard` against that at the top or change the `fatalError` message to give a clue to the consumer of function when they try to debug the crash. (2) Consider changing the tuple to `(String, UInt)` as the functions logic assumes that the weights passed are not negative.

Comment: @hashemi: Good points. Re (1): This can be checked with a precondition,  I have added that. Re (2): Yes, I had thought about that as well. The disadvantage is that then the function cannot be called with simple integer literals anymore: `colors =[("Red", UInt(20)), ...]`. – Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR you can specify the tuple's type explicitly to avoid the need to cast each number individually: `let colors: [(String, UInt)] = [...]`. Also, in real life situations, the numbers will likely be coming from user input or a database, so being careful with the types is even more important and literal input is less important.

Comment: @hashemi: You are right, and I have updated the answer according to your feedback.

Comment: FWIW, in _The Swift Programming Language,_ Apple explicitly advises that you use `Int`, “even when the values to be stored are known to be non-negative.” They advise that one “[use] `UInt` only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size.”